How to attach a version number to an ASP.NET Webforms application on .NET 4.8?
How do you version your .aspx web forms application? Such that you automatically increment the version upon each release?
Note: I am not referring to version controlling the source code.

Well, we find on SO about several 100,000 posts on asp.net and webforms.
So, why in the last 15+ years have we no posts or questions like yours?
The answer is simple:
Versioning some number for a web site is of little value. I mean, the end users don't care and so what if they see the web site is version 2.2.15? Are they the then to call you to update the web site?
Hence, user's don't care, since they never have to update their computers to use that web site, and as a result, no need in the last 20+ years has occurred for having some version number attached to the web site.
I mean, what benefit would some version number provide when the end user can't do anything of value with that information?
So, I can't see much if any value for the end users.
And for the developer? Well, the last version is the version you published to the web site that is now live. When you publish again, then once again, your web site is running your latest version. Once again, since you only in most cases are updating one web site for production on a server?
Then once again, little reason or need arises to have some version.
So, the above explains why desktop software and even class library code you may well use for that web site supports version numbers.
However, since the web site and users can't really consume, care or even do anything with a version number, then once again, no need really exists for some version number that means really nothing, and has no real use value I can determine here. So, you in most cases are only going to deploy to "one" server, and that's going to be production, and maybe a dev server. Hence, the web deployment model does not support, nor does it make sense for using some version number for the web site, when the final resting place is only one copy and one result on one server.
Of course, if you looking to keep track of versions for yourself, then once again, you will adopt source code control like everyone else, and you have every single update and date + time as to changes made. So, since web development is vast different then desktop software, then a version number not really required or applies to such a development model.
And toss in adoption source code control, then you have even less reasons to even spend the time and efforts using some "version" number of which it provides little or no use to your project management anyway.
So, the real answer?
Developers don't care nor use nor bother with some version number in web development land, since they are not deploying to large numbers of users, but in most cases are deploying to one final web site for production. This explains why you can't find a solution, since no one bothers with version numbers for web development.
I suppose you could add some .txt file, and increment it each time you publish, or even just open up the project, and in the assembly settings, enter a number each time you publish to production. Publishing not going to occur all that often anyway, so either manually type in a version number WHEN you are publishing the site as opposed to building the site during development.
So, you could type in a version number by opening the project properties page, "application", and then click on the assembly button.
And thus, you could type in a number when you publish. Hence here:

However, that version number is of little use, since when you actually use the publish option, then your source code is stripped out, and the above project page information is not included in the final published product for viewing anyway.
However, you can check the .dll created for the project, and the above information will exist. I can't see what you going to do with that information, and how it can help you, but the above information can thus be obtained, and even displayed on some admin page on the site.
So, the Assembly version, and the File version don't auto-increment for web-based projects for the above reasons.
